# Issues with HTML select

Tags: php, html

I wrote code which checks the user's language and opens a file (if the user's language is English it opens en.php and so on). I added an option that can change your language in settings, but this isn't working.

```php
# Checks for user's language
if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
   $lang = substr(explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[0],0,2)?:'en';
   if ($lang = $_COOKIE['lang']){
         $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
         setcookie("lang",$lang,time()+3650*24*60*60);
         $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
     } else {
       # $lang = substr(explode(',',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])[0],0,2)?:'en';
        setcookie("lang",$lang,time()+3650*24*60*60);
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
     }
   }

if ($lang === "en") {
        require 'translations/en.php'; # ENGLISH
     } # also every other language is included in elseif
```

```html
<!-- The form goes to that same page but at the beginning there are files included -->
<form method="post" action="settings.php" id="form2" name="form2">
<select class="settingsselect" name="language_select">
<option disabled selected>Select a Language</option>
<option value="something">some language</option>
</select>
</form>
<button class="updatesettings" type="submit" id="updatesettings" name="updatesettings" form="form2">Update Settings</button>
```

```php
# Update code
if (isset($_POST['updatesettings'])) {
    $lang = $_POST['language_select'];
    setcookie("lang",$lang,time()+3650*24*60*60);
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
}
```

```php
#files included in the beginning

require 'language_change.php';
require 'password_check.php';
require 'translation.php';
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean "not working"? What specifically is going wrong?

Comment: `if ($lang = $_COOKIE['lang']){` I suppose you want compare, not assign, rewrite with `if ($lang == $_COOKIE['lang']){`...

Comment: I suggest to use: `$lang = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2) : 'en';`...

Comment: Use to avoid Injection `if ($lang == htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['lang'], NULL, 'UTF-8')) {`

Comment: `$lang = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['lang'], NULL, 'UTF-8');` to be safe...

Comment: @Alessandro fixed that but when I click "update settings" nothing changes still.

Comment: @Jujunol By "not working" I mean literally nothing happens.

Comment: Before using `$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;` you have to serve `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }`

Comment: Since we can't guess what's wrong based on the information provided, I prepared an example of how your script might work, you can take inspiration from that ...

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It's pretty uncommon that "nothing happens" and the attempts to solve this are also pretty low

Comment: @Global Alliance: have you tried to modify your code as suggested in the comments?

Comment: `<option disabled selected>Select a Language</option>
<option value="something">some language</option>` are not well formed... you miss a large amount of working code...

Comment: Explain where is not working

Comment: `$_SESSION['lang']` is never used, `called` but `never used`...

Comment: I see other errors... your code lose of logic...

Comment: `if ($lang === "en") {` it's quite simple: `if ($lang == "en") {` you are not comparing the data type but only the value so `===` it's incorrect

Comment: @Alessandro Fixed the issue, the problem was in which file is included first.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some examples of php files you have provided are approximate and full of syntax errors, it probably won't work because your approach is wrong, try changing the logic of your php... and since we can't guess what's wrong (your code should be rewritten from scratch), I created a php example of how it should work, please don't copy it but take inspiration from it, thanks.

`index.php`

```
<?php
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['language']) ? htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['language'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2) : 'en'); ?>">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Change Language</title>
<?php
  function check_https() {
    $isSecure = false;
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on') {
      $isSecure = true;
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) == 'on') {
      $isSecure = true;
    }
    return $isSecure;
  }
  $check_https = check_https() ? 'https' : 'http';
  if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
    switch ($_POST['language']) {
      case 'en':
       if ($check_https == 'http') {
          setcookie('language', 'en', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        } else {
          setcookie('language', 'en', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
        }
        $_COOKIE['language'] = 'en';
      break;
      case 'it':
        if ($check_https == 'http') {
          setcookie('language', 'it', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        } else {
          setcookie('language', 'it', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
        }
        $_COOKIE['language'] = 'it';
      break;
      case 'fr':
        if ($check_https == 'http') {
          setcookie('language', 'fr', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        } else {
          setcookie('language', 'fr', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
        }
        $_COOKIE['language'] = 'fr';
      break;
      case 'es':
        if ($check_https == 'http') {
          setcookie('language', 'es', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
        } else {
          setcookie('language', 'es', time()+31556926 , '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
        }
        $_COOKIE['language'] = 'es';
      break;
      default:
    }
  }
?>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <style>
  <!--
    html {
      min-width: 360px !important;
    }
    .lang-content {
      width: 210px;
    }
  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="lang-content">
<fieldset><legend>Change Language</legend>
<form name="language" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<select name="language" class="lang">
<option class="my_language" value="en"<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language'] == 'en') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>en</option>
<option class="my_language" value="it"<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language'] == 'it') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>it</option>
<option class="my_language" value="fr"<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language'] == 'fr') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>fr</option>
<option class="my_language" value="es"<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['language']) && $_COOKIE['language'] == 'es') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>es</option>
</select>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="change" value="Change Language">
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE['language'])) {
    $my_language = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['language'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    if (file_exists(realpath("$my_language.php"))) {
      include("$my_language.php");
      echo PHP_EOL;
      echo PHP_EOL;
    } else {
      include("en.php");
      echo PHP_EOL;
      echo PHP_EOL;
    }
  } else {
    $my_language = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2) : 'en';
    if (file_exists(realpath("$my_language.php"))) {
      include("$my_language.php");
      echo PHP_EOL;
      echo PHP_EOL;
    } else {
      include("en.php");
      echo PHP_EOL;
      echo PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
?>
</body>

</html>
```

`en.php`

```
<?php
  echo "Welcome!";
?>
```

`es.php`

```
<?php
  echo "Bienvenida!";
?>
```

`fr.php`

```
<?php
  echo "Bienvenue!";
?>
```

`it.php`

```
<?php
  echo "Benvenuto!";
?>
```

[image: Live Example 1]

[image: Live Example 2]

The html generated is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <title>Change Language</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <style>
  <!--
    html {
      min-width: 360px !important;
    }
    .lang-content {
      width: 210px;
    }
  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="lang-content">
<fieldset><legend>Change Language</legend>
<form name="language" action="/test/index.php" method="post">
<select name="language" class="lang">
<option class="my_language" value="en" selected>en</option>
<option class="my_language" value="it">it</option>
<option class="my_language" value="fr">fr</option>
<option class="my_language" value="es">es</option>
</select>
<input class="button" type="submit" name="change" value="Change Language">
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>

Welcome!

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.